# Post return values with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I am using Code Igniter and I have the following Javascript function in my View. I have tried to echo values such as "error" from my handler function in the controller, but the "success" code is always ran in this function below instead.

Do I use echo or return to respond to the AJAX post? What value do I return for success and failure?

```
<script>
function removeDatacenter(id)
{
    var cfm = confirm("Do you wish to delete this datacenter?");

    if (cfm==true)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=base_url()?>datacenters/remove_handler.php",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function(result)
            {
                document.location.href = document.URL + "?result=success";
            },
            error: function(result)
            {
                document.location.href = document.URL + "?result=failed";
            }}
        );
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you echo something in your removeDatacenter() function, won't it be available as the response of your AJAX operation within your handler? I vaguely remember something along those lines...

Comment: You effect the DOM. Returning values in your JavaScript won't do any good, since your code in running asynchronously. Of course `echo` is PHP, and will be a String that is passed as the JavaScript `result` argument, upon `success` or `error`.

Comment: Note that `$.ajax()` will attempt to translate the data sent back from the Server automatically, possibly into JSON, if you used PHP's `echo json_encode($associativeArray)`. You can use the `dataType` property to force a data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The success-method runs if the ajax-request was successfully sent to your script. It does not say anything about what the request returned.

If you simply do `echo "error";` in your PHP-script, you can check the value in the `success`-method like this:

```
success: function(response) {
    if (response == "error") {
        document.location.href = document.URL + "?result=failed";
    }
    else {
        document.location.href = document.URL + "?result=success";
    }
}
```

Edit: People tend to use `json_encode` in the `PHP`-code and decode the json-string to an object in the javascript-code. That way you can send more structured data from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Any text you echo will be seen, by AJAX, as a success. Even if it's the word "error". In order for you to trigger the Javascript error handler, you need to trigger some sort of actual HTTP error. If you're just trying to trigger an error for testing purposes, you could throw an exception in your controller. Or point the AJAX request to a URL that doesn't exist on your server (then you'd get a 404 error).

By the way, the error callback you have in your Javascript is slightly off on the API. It might not matter depending on what you do in the error handler, but here's the full call:

```
error: function(xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  //handle error here
}
```